# Executar método quando inicializar a classe

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho uma classe chamada `ligacao` e quando inicializo ela(dentro de um botão) quero que outro método que está dentro dessa classe( que é iniciado em uma terceira classe) reexecute e mude de ObservableList.

Classe `ligacao` (o `boolean b` é que muda o ObservableList):

```
class ligacao {
    protected static boolean b;
    public licacao(boolean b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    static FilteredList<Person> filtrar;
    public static FilteredList get(ObservableList<Person> obs, ObservableList<Person> obs2){
        filtrar = new FilteredList<>(obs, p -> true);
        if(b == true){
            filtrar.removeAll(obls);
            filtrar = new FilteredList<>(obs2, p -> true); 
        }else{
            filtrar.removeAll(obs2);
            filtrar = new FilteredList<>(obs, p -> true);
        }
        return filtrar;
    }
}
```

Classe em que a classe `ligacao` é inicializada:

```
    carne.setOnAction((Carne) -> {
        try {
            boolean b = false;
            System.out.println(b);

            if(carne.getText().endsWith("Carnê")){
                carne.setText("Tabela");
                System.out.println(b);
                b = true;
                System.out.println(b);
            }else{
                carne.setText("Carnê");
                System.out.println(b);
                b = false;
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            System.out.println(b);
            new ligacao(b);
            System.out.println(b + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
```

(terceira classe) Onde inicializa o método `get` da classe `ligacao`:

```
FilteredList<Person> filtrar = ligacao.get(obs(), obs2());
```

O problema que que não muda o método `get`.

O que faço?

Comment: É possível em JAVA um método *static* usar um atributo não *static*? Para isso ser possível, estou a pensar em C#, seria declarar `b` como `public static boolean b;`

Comment: Estava assim é que eu acabei apagando.

Comment: Acredito que esse seu código não compile. Um construtor não pode acessar uma variável estática. Além disso ele está com o nome errado.

Comment: Me desculpe por ter colocado o código faltando algumas partes, mas o código compila.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes Não existe nenhuma regra que proíba um construtor acessar uma variável estática. É verdade que isso não é lá uma boa prática de programação, mas o compilador e a JVM aceitam isso normalmente.

Comment: Haha verdade, permite mesmo :)

Comment: @ramaral o `this.b = b;` compila sim, pois é permitido acessar um campo estático usando uma variável ao invés do nome da classe (no caso, a variável é o `this`). Entretanto, isso é uma péssima prática de programação e não deveria ser feito nunca, mas a linguagem permite sim.

Comment: @VictorStafusa O meu comentário não se referia a isso. Na altura o campo `b` **não** estava declarado como estático e era acedido no método estático `get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos ver a sua primeira classe:

```
class ligacao {
   // ...
   public licacao(boolean b){
   // ...
```

Aqui temos um erro de compilação, pois o nome do construtor deveria ser `ligacao`, e não `licacao`. Além disso, a convenção de nomes dita que nomes de classes iniciam com letras maiúsculas, e desobedecer essa conveção não é uma boa ideia.

Um pouco mais abaixo:

```
filtrar.removeAll(obls);
```

Não há nenhuma variável `obls`. Acho que você quis dizer `obs`.

Também neste método:

```
if(b == true){
```

Por favor, **NUNCA** compare uma expressão ou variável booleana com `== true` ou `== false`. Isso é uma má prática de programação. Ao invés disso, use simplesmente assim:

```
if (b) {
```

E se quisesse comparar com `false`, bastaria usar isso:

```
if (!b) {
```

O método também tem como retorno `FilteredList` bruto sem o tipo genérico ao invés de `FilteredList<Person>`. O compilador deve estar dando algumas *warnings* dos tipos *rawtypes* e *unchecked* por causa disso.

Olhando aonde você usa a classe `ligacao` de fora dela, temos estes dois lugares:

```
new ligacao(b);
ligacao.get(obs(), obs2());
```

No primeiro caso, a instância de `ligacao` recém-criada não será utilizada para nada e será perdida para ser devorada pelo coletor de lixo. O único efeito disso será alterar o valor da variável estática `b` (que não vejo sentido ser `protected` ao invés de `private`). No segundo caso, o método `get` é estático. Como conclusão, instâncias da classe `ligacao` são inúteis, e portanto não tem sentido de serem instanciadas. O construtor que você usou nada mais é do que um *setter* disfarçado, e usar construtores para isso é algo horroroso. A sugestão neste caso seria eliminar o construtor e usar um *setter* estático:

```
class Ligacao {
    private static boolean b;
    public static void setFlag(boolean novoValor) {
        b = novoValor;
    }
```

```
// Na segunda classe:
Ligacao.setFlag(b);
```

Vamos aproveitar e dar uma olhada no código que veio da segunda classe, e tentar rastrear qual é o valor do `b` dela:

```
carne.setOnAction((Carne) -> {
    try {
        boolean b = false;
        System.out.println(false); // Escrevia b, mas b é sabidamente false.

        if(carne.getText().endsWith("Carnê")){
            carne.setText("Tabela");
            System.out.println(false); // Escrevia b, mas b é sabidamente false.
            b = true;
            System.out.println(true); // Escrevia b, mas b é sabidamente true.
        }else{
            carne.setText("Carnê");
            System.out.println(false); // Escrevia b, mas b é sabidamente false.
            b = false; // Não faz nada, pois b já é false.
            System.out.println(false); // Escrevia b, mas b é sabidamente false.
        }
        System.out.println(b);
        Ligacao.setFlag(b);
        System.out.println(b + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

});
```

Vamos simplificar então, tirando os `System.out.println` desnecessários e as instruções desnecessárias:

```
carne.setOnAction((Carne) -> {
    try {
        boolean b = false;
        if (carne.getText().endsWith("Carnê")) {
            carne.setText("Tabela");
            b = true;
        } else {
            carne.setText("Carnê");
        }
        Ligacao.setFlag(b);
        System.out.println(b + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Podemos simplificar um pouco mais se notarmos que `b` só será verdadeiro se a condição do `if` for verdadeira e com isso podemos usá-la diretamente como o valor de `b`:

```
carne.setOnAction((Carne) -> {
    try {
        boolean b = carne.getText().endsWith("Carnê");
        carne.setText(b ? "Tabela" : "Carnê");
        Ligacao.setFlag(b);
        System.out.println(b + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Aqui, ainda cabe questionar o nome do parâmetro do lambda: `Carne`. Isso não é um nome apropriado, pois isso é uma variável e portanto deveria começar com letra minúscula. Além disso, ter duas variáveis cujo nome difere apenas pelas maiúsculas e minúsculas, a saber `carne` e `Carne` é uma má prática de programação pois deixa o código bem confuso. Sugiro renomear o `Carne` para alguma outra coisa.

Agora, voltando a sua primeira classe, percebe-se que você esqueceu o `private` na declaração do campo estático `filtrar`, mas vamos dar uma olhada no que o método `get` faz (já aplicadas as correções que sugeri antes):

```
private static FilteredList<Person> filtrar;
public static FilteredList<Person> get(ObservableList<Person> obs, ObservableList<Person> obs2) {
    filtrar = new FilteredList<>(obs, p -> true);
    if (b) {
        filtrar.removeAll(obs);
        filtrar = new FilteredList<>(obs2, p -> true); 
    }else{
        filtrar.removeAll(obs2);
        filtrar = new FilteredList<>(obs, p -> true);
    }
    return filtrar;
}
```

Se `b` for verdadeiro eis o que ocorre:

1. Cria uma lista com todos os elementos de `obs` e o atribui à variável estática `filtra`, portanto perdendo a referência anterior da lista não importando o que ela era.
2. Remove todos os elementos de `obs` que estão na lista (e portanto todos os elementos), o que resulta em uma lista vazia.
3. Cria uma outra lista com todos os elementos de `obs2`. A lista anterior é perdida para o coletor de lixo, e portanto o trabalho realizado nela nos passos 1 e 2 foi desperdiçado.
4. Retorna a lista com os elementos que estavam em `obs2`.

Se `b` for falso:

1. Cria uma lista com todos os elementos de `obs` e o atribui à variável estática `filtra`, portanto perdendo a referência anterior da lista não importando o que ela era.
2. Remove todos os elementos de `obs2` que estão na lista, o que resulta em uma lista com os elementos de `obs` que não estão em `obs2`. Se não houver nenhum elemento que esteja em ambas as listas, isso não vai fazer nada.
3. Cria uma outra lista com todos os elementos de `obs`. A lista anterior é perdida para o coletor de lixo, e portanto o trabalho realizado nela nos passos 1 e 2 foi desperdiçado.
4. Retorna a lista com os elementos que estavam em `obs`.

Observe que em ambos os casos, a lista que fica guardada ao final é irrelevante, pois da forma como o método `get` foi codificado, qualquer tentativa de acessar o conteúdo desta lista necessariamente a fará ser perdida.

Tudo isso ficaria muito mais simples assim:

```
public static FilteredList<Person> get(ObservableList<Person> obs, ObservableList<Person> obs2) {
    return new FilteredList<>(b ? obs : obs2, p -> true);
}
```

E é assim que o seu código fica no final das contas:

```
class Ligacao {
    private static boolean b;

    public static void setFlag(boolean novoValor) {
        b = novoValor;
    }

    public static FilteredList<Person> get(ObservableList<Person> obs, ObservableList<Person> obs2) {
        return new FilteredList<>(b ? obs : obs2, p -> true);
    }
}
```

```
carne.setOnAction(x -> {
    try {
        boolean b = carne.getText().endsWith("Carnê");
        carne.setText(b ? "Tabela" : "Carnê");
        Ligacao.setFlag(b);
        System.out.println(b + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

```
FilteredList<Person> filtrar = Ligacao.get(obs(), obs2());
```

Por fim, algumas pessoas podem achar que acessar o campo estático usando `this` causa um erro de compilação. Isso não é verdade, pois é permitido acessar um campo estático usando uma variável ao invés do nome da classe e no caso, a variável é o `this`). Entretanto, isso é uma péssima prática de programação e não deveria ser feito nunca, mas a linguagem permite.

E também acessar uma variável estática de dentro do construtor é perfeitamente válido na linguagem Java. Na maioria das vezes (nem sempre, existem algumas exceções), fazer isso não é boa prática de programação e tende a deixar o código ruim e propenso a ocorrência de *bugs*, mas a linguagem Java permite.

Comment: Esses erros nos nomes das variáveis era por que me foi aconselhado que  usa-se nomes mais simples e quando fui trocar não deu muito certo. E essa parte `carne.setText(b ? "Tabela" : "Carnê");` não tinha conhecimento disso. Mas mesmo corrigindo o código, ele vai toda vez que eu clicar no botão ele vai mudar o `Person`(`obs()`) padrão para o outro `Person`(`obs2()`)?(Aqui fica o mesmo `Person`) Mas Obrigado por ter me alerdado sobre o `this` e outras cosas.

Comment: @lucasdaniel Na sua terceira classe, o que os métodos `obs()` e `obs2()` retornam?

Comment: São um leitura no banco de dados e retornam `ObservableList<Person>`, cada um é uma tabela do banco de dados.

Comment: Tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Isso começou a funcionar quando usei FXML, e já que todo(ou quase todo) o código vai ficar em uma só classe faz-se assim:`tableview.getItems().clear()` e `tableview.getItems().addAll(b ? obs : obs2)`. Valeu por responder e desculpe por demorar para marcar como certar.